# Change button text color to a hexavalue

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have 2 buttons (button-A and button-B). When I click button-A, I want to change the text color of Button-B but I want to give it in a hexadecimal value. I have seen a lot of links for hexadecimal value font color but I am unable to figure out how to use. I want to change the text font color of button to value (#191f2d). In swift iOS. Please help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Appdelegate file after import statement add this

```
extension UIColor {
    // Usage: UIColor(hex: 0xFC0ACE)
    convenience init(hex: Int) {
        self.init(hex: hex, alpha: 1)
    }

    // Usage: UIColor(hex: 0xFC0ACE, alpha: 0.25)
    convenience init(hex: Int, alpha: Double) {
        self.init(
            red: CGFloat((hex >> 16) & 0xff) / 255,
            green: CGFloat((hex >> 8) & 0xff) / 255,
            blue: CGFloat(hex & 0xff) / 255,
            alpha: CGFloat(alpha))
    }
}
```

and wherever you want to use it just use it like this

```
button.setTitleColor(UIColor.init(hex: 0x191f2d), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

use 0x before Hex value instead of #.

Hope it will help You.

Comment: Thanks a lot @JigneshP it was a great solution! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need an extension of `UIColor`, that takes the hex value and creates an `UIImage`. There's a lot of extensions out there, a simple Google search finds many results...

I personally use this:
https://github.com/thii/SwiftHEXColors

Just follow the instructions or drag and drop `SwiftHEXColors.swift` file to your project.